# Is there a way to get all processes running with MainWindowHandler in UWP?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, uwp, process

I want to get all Processes running on the local machine and test if they have a MainWindow Handler. Do you know any way to do this?

Comment: Hello, in UWP applications, you cannot get the window handler like traditional Win32 applications, and you cannot directly operate on Process. What are the reasons for this? Maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: I am using an AppService now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using an appservice now [Click here for more information about appservices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-services) because it isnt possible (I searched for more than two weeks) to get the MainWindowHandler in UWP. I created an WPF application that is getting the processes and sending this via appservice instead

Comment: It seems like I'm stuck in a similar boat. Could you please explain how you were able to communicate between the WPF application and the UWP one using app services? All the documented examples demonstrate communication between two UWP applications.

Comment: @Hibnuhishath create an appservice and run a little "subprogram" that communicates with the UWP